# How to fix problem with pod's issue "pod has unbound immediate persistentvolumeclaims" in Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, microk8s

I want setup a working environment on local machine where I had installed microk8s before. And when I install Jenkins from helm chart (stable/jenkins) I have problem

> pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

I started cluster in Linux Ubuntu 18.x which installed and working in Oracle Virtual box. Please give me any tips.

Persistent volume started without any problems. I tried to change size of PV but that didn't help with problem. In pod's log there is only one sentence about that pod is initializing. Searching of similar problem gave me nothing.

Pod's log content:

> container "jazzed-anteater-jenkins" in pod
> "jazzed-anteater-jenkins-69886499b4-6gbhn" is waiting to start:
> PodInitializing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case problem was related with droped IPtables FORWARD policy. I had investigated it with the help of `microk8s.inspect` command.

InitContainer couldn't get access to the Internet and it stopped deployment of whole pod with main container. Solving was easy

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

and redeployment with Helm.